# Capitalize first letter of each group of letters in a string

Tags: java, string

I've got the following string `s`:

```
String s = "abbcccdddd";
```

I need to capitalize first letters of each group of letters, like:

```
ABbCccDddd
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @QBrute Not necessarily a duplicate though. The OP seems to want to capitalize the first character of each sequence of the same character, not just the first character of the string.

Comment: Try looping through your string one character at a time, and keep track of the previous letter. If the current letter doesn't match the previous one, then you need to capitalize the current letter. If you're still unable to solve it, edit your question with your code and the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String capFirst(String s){
    
    //String we want to return
    String result = "";
    
    //The first letter will always be capitalized; concatenate it to our result
    result += s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    
    //Iterate across original string s
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
        
        //If the current letter is equal to the previous letter
        if (s.substring(i,i+1).equalsIgnoreCase(s.substring(i-1,i))){
            
            //Concatenate to our return string as is (lower case)
            result += s.substring(i,i+1);
            
        } else {
            
            //Otherwise, concatenate to our return string as upper case
            result += s.substring(i,i+1).toUpperCase();
            
        }
    }
    
    //Return final result
    return result;
}
```

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abbcccdddd";
    System.out.println(capFirst(s));
}
```

**Output**

```
ABbCccDddd
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 groupingBy:**

You can implement the same using Java8 `groupingBy` feature in which you can group the same elements and find the frequency of each element and add it to a list as shown below:

**Code:**

```
public class Convert {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abbcccdddd";
        
        Map<Character,Long> countMap = s.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char)x)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                    LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        countMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
            for(int i = 0; i < v; i++){
                if(i==0){
                    sb.append(k.toString().toUpperCase());
                } else{
                    sb.append(k);
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABbCccDddd
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way. Read the comments in code:

```
String s = "abbcccdddd";
    
String curLetter = "";   // Holds the current letter being processed in string.
String prevLetter = "";  // Holds the current letter AFTER its been processed.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");  // Used to build the string.
    
// Iterate through each character of the string `s`...
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

    // Get the current letter to process.
    curLetter = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));

    // Is it the same s the previous letter procesed?
    if (!curLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(prevLetter)) {
        // No, then make the letter Upper Case
        curLetter = curLetter.toUpperCase();
    }
    // Add the current letter to the String Builder
    sb.append(curLetter);
        
    /* Make the prevLetter hold the curLetter for 
       next iteration comparison.      */
    prevLetter = curLetter; 
}
    
// Apply what is in the StringBuilder into a newString variable.
String newString = sb.toString();
    
// Display newString in Console Window.
System.out.println(newString);
```